# Magento nucleanup.php script not working on plesk server?

Tags: php, magento, curl, plesk

I have set up a cron job in plesk to run a cleanup script to clear database log files, but it does not seem to work, I have followed this tutorial http://www.nublue.co.uk/forums/topic/271/reducing-the-size-of-your-magento-database/

I have a similar script running on another server which works ok using the script at: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/maintenance_script

I don't seem to get any errors when i run the scripts but it does not clear the files ?

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you changed the database- and table names? You could also try inserting the SQL code in phpmyadmin and look whether there are SQL-errors.

Comment: @DRP96 no the database and table names never change and cant generate any errors in the mysql db ? thanks

Comment: @Ledgemonkey did you check "curl" installed in your server?

Comment: @OC The server in running magento so must have Curl installed ?? but will check thanks

Comment: @Ledgemonkey PHP_Curl should be installed.

Comment: Ok seems to be working now many thanks for your help, i will post as answer many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure Php_curl is enabled on your server...